# Java loop through nested JSON object

Tags: java, json, loops

I have a JSON object that I need to loop through to get all of the account_id's and id's if they exist together in the same child object and add them to one array list.

```json
{
    "content": {
        "sections": [
            {
                "type": "one",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "id": "3412434"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "two",
                "title": "Second Section",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "id": "7654"
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": "1234",
                        "id": "123456"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "three",
                "title": "Third Section",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "account_id": "5678",
                        "id": "654321"
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": "5465763",
                        "id": "0864352342434"
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": "856864745",
                        "id": "97867562542"
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": "43214545",
                        "id": "86474653634"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This JSON object is dynamic, so I wanted to loop through the entire sections array list to see if the account_id, id combo exist, but I'm having trouble drilling down through the nesting. This is what I am currently doing. This is my RxJava method. I know it's incorrect and is only grabbing the first account_id, id combo for each section object:

```java
public void getSections() {
    disposables.add(repository.getContent()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Content>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Content content) {

                    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<String> idStringList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(int i = 0; i < content.getContent().getSections().size(); i++){
                        if(content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getType().equals("two")){
                            idList.add(content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getContent().get(i).getAccountId() + ":" + content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getContent().get(i).getId());
                        }
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < content.getContent().getSections().size(); i++){
                        if(content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getType().equals("three")){
                            idList.add(content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getContent().get(i).getAccountId() + ":" + content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getContent().get(i).getId());
                        }
                    }

                    sectionsIdsString = String.join(",", idList);
                    getMoreContent(sectionsIdsString);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
}
```

How can I loop through this object to get all of the account_id's, id's?

Comment: need a [mcve] please.

Comment: Java for each is your friend https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/enhanced-for-loop
It looks like you need to loop through each `section` and in each `section` you need to loop through each `content`.  Hence, to traverse your nested structure, you need nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that in your for-loops, you are using the same index i for both section and content (i.e. `content.getContent().getSections().get(i).getContent().get(i).getAccountId()`).

This means that for each section 1, you will only grab the first content object, for section 2 you will only grab the 2nd content object, and for section 3 you will only grab the 3rd content object.

You could also build the String directly, instead of building a list and then joining the entries.

You could try something like this:

```
public void getSections() {
    disposables.add(repository.getContent()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Content>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Content content) {

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                    for(int i = 0; i < content.getSections().size(); i++) {
                         for(int j = 0; j < content.getSections().get(i).getContent().size(); j++) {
                              if(sb.length() == 0) {
                                   sb.append(content.getSections().get(i).getContent().get(j).getAccountId() + ":" + content.getSections().get(i).getContent().get(j).getId());
                              } else {
                                   sb.append("," + content.getSections().get(i).getContent().get(j).getAccountId() + ":" + content.getSections().get(i).getContent().get(j).getId());
                              }
                         }
                    }
                    getMoreContent(sb.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
}
```